# Is there any testnet faucet for ETC Ethereum Classic Coin?

Tags: testnets, ethereum-classic, faucets, morden

Not able to get testing ETC from available faucet https://etcfaucet.info/, is there any other faucet or way to get ETC for tesing?

Comment: Please mark my question as solution if it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

See this issue on github: https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/issues/708

You have to ask them in the group.

Comment: Have already referred that reference but not getting any kind of solution.

Comment: you want the etc on testnet right?

Comment: @Rudrika otherwise you should probably just mine some blocks on the testnet

Comment: Not able to mine blocks because of compatibility issue with available hardware.

Comment: I cant think of another option. Maybe you need a friend how has ETC

Answer (score 1):

We have a Kotti Faucet here: http://kottifaucet.me/

You'll need to use your social media account to request funds by tweeting out and sharing the link to your tweet in the form. Instructions are found in the link I shared

You can follow my guide for running Kotti so you can test out ETC's POA testnet: https://medium.com/ethereum-classic/kotti-solidity-etc-oh-my-2ae36926454d

I can happily send you some test Kotti coins if you DM me your Kotti address on Twitter (it's only test coins and my info is found on the Medium article).

Comment: Yes, I have referred this article on medium, and tried to get test coins using given faucet.

Comment: Will DM you Kotti Address for testcoins on Twitter.

Comment: More resources for Kotti are on Github: https://github.com/eth-classic/kotti